# Makefile does not work, @if, @else, @then not found

Tags: makefile

This is the section of my Makefile which fails

```
b2dsetup:
            @$(ECHO) "Goes in b2dsetup"; \
            @if [-d "/external/src/Box2D"]; \
            @then $(PRINTF) "Option1"; \
            @else; \
            @$(ECHO) "Option2"; \
                    @cd /external/src/; \
                    @tar cfv Box2D.tgz Box2D; \
            @fi;
```

and gives the following error:

```
Goes in b2dsetup
bash: line 1: @if: command not found
bash: line 2: @then: command not found
bash: line 3: @else: command not found
bash: line 4: @/bin/echo: No such file or directory
bash: line 5: @cd: command not found
bash: line 6: @tar: command not found
bash: line 7: @fi: command not found
Makefile_g30:71: recipe for target 'b2dsetup' failed
make: *** [b2dsetup] Error 127

shell returned 2
```

I tried lots of syntactical changes and googling but nothing helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only put the `@` on the first line of a multiline script.

```
b2dsetup:
        @$(ECHO) "Goes in b2dsetup"; \
        if [-d "/external/src/Box2D"]; \
        then $(PRINTF) "Option1"; \
        else \
            $(ECHO) "Option2"; \
            cd /external/src/; \
            tar cfv Box2D.tgz Box2D; \
        fi
```

Or:

```
b2dsetup:
        @$(ECHO) "Goes in b2dsetup"
        @if [-d "/external/src/Box2D"]; \
        then $(PRINTF) "Option1"; \
        else \
            $(ECHO) "Option2"; \
            cd /external/src/; \
            tar cfv Box2D.tgz Box2D; \
        fi
```